# Getting a php file in an iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have two files one is `index.php` which contains a form which gets submitted to abc.php.Now the problem is  have a frame in `index.php` where in i want to display the datas that i got after submitting the form to `abc.php`.I tried but m not able to it.Hope i hav mentioned all the thngs required. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: generally recommended not to use frames of any sort.

Comment: I think you will have to reload the frame/iframe after the data was uploaded via form (unless the form is inside the frame, then it would get updated automatically). I guess you can use javascript to reload a frame, but I am not sure.

Comment: @dagon i got two forms  in index.php wic i need to display after being processed from the database ..how can i do that ...any sugesstions??

Comment: @aufziehvogel i tried the reload thng its not giving wat i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Set your form's target ([phpfiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nm1-0hz)):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit_to_frame']))
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['the_data']);
}
else
{
?>
<iframe id="the_frame" name="the_frame"></iframe>
<form method="POST" target="the_frame">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_to_frame" value="true" />
    <input type="text" name="the_data"/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thaks jon i got tat but i hav a select tag that gets it data populated from database first then based on the selection of the select tag the values will be dsplayed in frames. There is a interaction with the database then i can imlement the above problems.I guess u got wat i wanna say.

Comment: @KrisnaSharma can you post your index.php and abc.php?