# Set URL as variable of input in parent document

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I have a piece of code (CURL) from which I can extract data like this:

```
  <?php
    $url = "http://www.nu.nl/";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $curl_scraped_page;
    ?>
```

I also have a HTML file with an input. I would like to replace the physical URL with a dynamic one, so setting it as a variable. The variable should be the value of the input which is in the parent document. So the php file is echoed in an iframe. Is this possible? I have Googled and search Stack but I only found this answer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428079/getting-a-php-file-in-an-iframe)  Which I could not alter to want I want. (I'm new at PHP)

Comment: How many PHP/HTML files are you dealing with? And how many requests to user's browser in this process? Can you provide a little more info about what this script's purpose is?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, are you trying to make some kind of "proxy script" to get the HTML code of a web page? For example, something that you call as `<iframe src="script.php?url=http://www.nu.nl" ...>` and gets the contents of that URL inside the frame? But then, why are you not including the source site directly?

Comment: Please underline (and add the code that has it if not already in there) the physical URL in your question you want to replace. Right now in your question it is not clear what you're asking about.

Comment: @JRL Hi, I'm not sure what you mean..This is just my own little project, using my own browser. I only have one php file with only the code above inside it and HTML file with an input. At this point I'm only interested in "changing the URL with input"

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Hi, the physical URL is "http://www.nu.nl/" as in the question. However I need it to be a variable. I know in Jquery I would do something like this: `var $variable = $(parent.document.body).find('input').val();`

Comment: @user1532999: Okay, good to know, I suggest to read it how this works in PHP from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: @Ale Hi, Yes Im trying to make some sort of proxy script, actually I already have the script which is the code above:-) Like I mentioned, Im new at PHP. I know this should be very easy to do but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Thanks for the link, cant give you +1, need reputation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change your `echo` line in your PHP file to this:

`echo base64_encode($curl_scraped_page);`

And your `$url` assignment to this:

`$url = $_POST['url'];`

And use this jQuery (you can use plain JavaScript if you wish, jQuery is just nicer to work with):

```
$('#getPage')click(function() { //When the button "getButton" is clicked
    //Make a POST request to your PHP file with the value of the textbox as the URL
    $.post('myCURLPage.php', {url: $('#myTextInput').val()}, function(encodedData) {
        //Set the iFrames "src" attribute to the base64 encoded HTML page returned from you r PHP script
        $('#myiFrame').attr('src', 'data:text/html;base64,'+encodedData);
    });
});
```

(This presumes you have a button on your page with the ID set to `getPage` and the iFrame with an ID of `myiFrame` and an input box with an ID of `myTextInput`)

*Disclaimer: I've not tested this code, but theoretically it should work.*

Comment: Testing it, one moment please

Comment: Hi, I have tested it on my server and it doesn't work. Nothing happened on the click of button, console is not giving errors. Actually the call to myCURLPage.php is never made..I have put an example at Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BsKct/ I know it doesn't work there but I just want to show you what I did. I put the proxy in the CSS department (Cant give you +1 need Reputation..)

Comment: Isn't base64_encode for protecting code? I don't really need that since Im only giving URL

Comment: Nope, base64 is just a way of encoding data. Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-the-use-of-base-64-encoding

Comment: I don't thing that it can work on jsfiddle, putting PHP code in the CSS section wont run the code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BsKct/4/ Copy that HTML into your file. The jQuery  code needed to be inside the `$(document).ready` function because it was trying to bind an event to an element that didn't exist yet.

Comment: I removed the click event and now the call is made. But now I get this in Iframe: `src="data:text/html;base64, "` The Iframe is empty, no data

Comment: Hard code a URL in your PHP file and check the base64 encoded output. it should look like a random bunch of alpha/numeric characters

Comment: I copied your code, same result. The Iframe gets a src like this `src="data:text/html;base64, "` The Iframe however is empty. I don't know what the src 'code' means. It seems its just calls for what you have put in Jquery `$('#myiFrame').attr('src', 'data:text/html;base64`

Comment: I have hardcode the URL and now Im getting a very long line of letters (not numbers) which don't make sense

Comment: Ok, you *should* just need to change the `$_GET` to `$_POST` (my bad)

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH:-) Its a work of art. Im sorry I cant give you +1 for effort due to no "reputation"